# Is it possible to build a DLL which can support multiple versions of .NET references?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am having a project in which I am using  a `DLL` build using `C#` with some `.NET` reference having assembly  `version 10.0`.

But, while running my application on another machine which is having `VS 2012` and the assembly `version 12.0`, application is not able to load the `DLL`.

After some `R & D` I come to know about the version dependency of `DLL`.

So, Can any one tell me how do I build a `DLL` which can be load using available `.NET` version on client's machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make DLL working on multiple versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192411/how-to-make-dll-working-on-multiple-versions)

Comment: Don't ask the same question again because you didn't like the answer, instead go update your other question to provide more details.

Comment: Pretty unlikely you can hide that difference.  Be specific, what is the full name of that DLL?

Comment: @HansPassant these are the names of dlls of TFS `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.C‌​lient.dll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .net assembly targets a single version of the .net framework.

You need to ensure that the target .net framework is installed on any machine on which you run the program. Either target a version of the framework that ships with your minimum supported OS version, or install the appropriate .net framework redistributable package.

Comment: Hi.. Is that mean we can not develop a DLL which can choose available version of reference from machine? 

For Example:  
if .NET framework 3.5 is in machine then it will select the references from framework 3.5 or for 4.0 from that version?
I am asking this because for my application it is not feasible to install any of the redistributable package on client machine.

Comment: So pick a framework version that ships with your min supported os and go with that. However, in my view it is futile to hope to avoid having to install redistributable.

Comment: yeah currently I am picking up the min supported framework and depending on choosing one of the DLL for my application. Actually I need to avoid to have different dlls for different framework versions as functionally of all dlls is same.

Comment: No need for multiple DLLs. Pick, say .net 3, and it's present on Vista and up.

Comment: But the reference dlls like `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll`, `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll`,`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll` will not be available in the client machine  for the default .net framework right?

Comment: I don't know. I think I'm wasting my time now. It doesn't feel as though you want help. It doesn't feel as though you are listening. It sounds like you've already decided on a course of action.

Comment: sorry to say but I havnt decided any solution till now and thanks for help and suggestion it helps me a lot

Comment: You can create for .net 3, 3.5, 4. they should be mentioned in config file. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/886256/NET-versioning-and-multi-targeting-on-Csharp-appli

Comment: @ananda Please can you write an answer to that effect, and I will petition the asker to change the accept. Or edit my answer to correct it.

Comment: Well first the first programmer should have both .NETs, then he can specify both of them as mentioned in the article.

Comment: @ananda It would be helpful if there was an answer to say that. Can you provide one?